# How do I resize an image that's located INSIDE my CSS?

Tags: css, image, resize, size

How do I resize the image?
I have tried using properties like `height`, `width`, etc, but this does not work. I can't seem to resize it if I pull it from inside the CSS

```css
.project p::before {
    content:url('logo.png');
    position:relative; /* or absolute */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, pseudo-elements such as `::before` have a `display` of `inline`, so size properties such as `width` and `height` do not apply to them. To correct this, you will need to set it to `display: inline-block` or `display: block`.

In addition to this, instead of using `content` to load the URL, you'll need to set `content` to an empty value and make use of `background` (or `background-image`) for the image itself.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.project p::before {
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/100/100');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  content: ''; /* Required */
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the content blank and put the image as the background. Then you can set the width and height of the pseudo element and manipulate the picture with background properties like size or position. More here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

```
.project p::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-img: url("some url here");
    background-origin: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```